# Schedule Task to start based on a file

Tags: windows-server-2008, scheduled-tasks

I have a folder in my Windows 2008 Server.

I have a Windows Scheduled Task that runs every 15 minutes that will read the files from the above mentioned folder and store it in the database. Once stored, the file will be moved to a different folder.

Is there any way that we can schedule the task so that it kicks off the moment it sees a new file in the folder instead of waiting for 15 minutes or run even if there are no files in the folder?

Please help.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you are willing to write a program in .NET I think you can use the `FileSystemWatcher` class to do this.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filesystemwatcher.aspx

I believe this can be used from **PowerShell** as well, never done that though!